# Why the lists are binded?

Tags: flutter, dart

Please can someone explain me why when i change the first list the second one changes?

```
List t = [2,5,4,7];
List b = t;
b.sort((a,b)=>a-b);
print(t);
print(b);
```

Console:
[2, 4, 5, 7]
[2, 4, 5, 7]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dart never clones an object instance. This applies to list, but also to all objects:

```dart
class Foo {
  int a;
}

void main() {
  final first = Foo();
  first.a = 42;
  final second = first;
  second.a = 21;

  print(first); // 21
  print(second); // 21
}
```

If you don't want that and create a copy of a list instead, use `List.from` or `...`:

```dart
final list = [0, 1, 2];
final clone = [...list];

list.add(42);
print(clone); // (0, 1, 2);
print(list); // (0, 1, 2, 42);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, both the variable b & t refers to same arrayList. Create new list b with all elements of t, then you will get your desired output.

Answer (score 0):

"List b = t;" is assign t's address, not value.

[Pass by value vs. pass by reference](https://www.educative.io/edpresso/pass-by-value-vs-pass-by-reference)

Answer (score 0):

Because `List` is a reference type.
So when you're assigning `b` to `t`, `b` points to the very same address in the memory where `t` memory had been allocated.